# MailGun API Batch Sending Python

Tags: python, send, mailgun

I am trying to define a send protocol on the MailGun API with Python.

I followed their [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#batch-sending) but it doesn't seem to work.

So, I have a dictionary like this:

```
     {'email1@domain.pt': {'filepath': 'XXX.pdf',
      'ANF': 0000,
      'folderfilepath': 'C:\XXX\XXX.pdf',
      'index': 77,
      'idt': XXX,
      'Titulo': 'Estimado Dr. ',
      'Farmacia': 'XXX',
      'Nome': 'XXX XXX',
      'Reports': 1,
      'Campanhas': 1,
      'Morada': 'XXX, XXX',
      'CP': 'XXXX-XXX',
      'Localidade': 'XXX',
      'Distrito': 'XXX',
      'Estado': 'Efetiva'},
     {'email2@domain.pt': {'filepath': 'YYY.pdf',
      ...
```

I created a list to get the keys like:

```
      maillist = ['email1@domain.pt', 'email2@domain.pt']
```

And I my function looks like this:

```
def send_complex_message_batch():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/rede.XXX/messages",
        auth=("api", "key-XXXXXXX"),
        data={'recipient-variables': recipientVars,
              "from": "Excited User <geral@XXX.pt>",
              "to": maillist,
              "subject": "%recipient.Titulo%",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness, %recipient.Farmacia%, Sr. %recipient.Nome%",
              "html": "<html>HTML version of the body</html>"})
```

And it just won't send, it returns ERROR CODE 400:

```
Bad Request - Often missing a required parameter
```

The thing is that it doesn't show on the MailGun Logs as the messages were not sent, so I can't check whats missing.

**I'm lost here, has anyone had a problem like this?**

And if I want to go even further, adding a variable attachment, it gets even worse:

```
def send_complex_message_batch():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/rede.XXX/messages",
        auth=("api", "key-XXX"),
        data={'recipient-variables': recipientVars,
              "from": "Excited User <geral@XXX.pt>",
              "to": maillist,
              "subject": "%recipient.Titulo%",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness, %recipient.Farmacia%, Sr. %recipient.Nome%",
              "html": "<html>HTML version of the body</html>"},
        files=[("attachment", ("%recipient.filepath%", open("%recipient.folderfilepath%", "rb").read()))])
```

With error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '%recipient.folderfilepath%'
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help as I couldn't find much with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A solution would be to do a FOR loop and trigger the function "n" times, but I would really like to avoid this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making a POST request, the data passed as `recipientVars` should be cast into a JSON string. So simply `json.dumps(recipientVars)` should hopefully fix the problem (after importing `json`, of course).